# How to mark CheckItem in Trello as "complete"?

Tags: python, api, trello

Is there any ways to mark CheckItem in Trello as "complete"?

Have not found any methods in [Python TrelloAPI](https://pythonhosted.org/trello/trello.html) or [Trello Api](http://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/checklist) for updating CheckItems in Checklists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is [POST /1/checklists/[idChecklist]/checkItems](http://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/checklist#post-1-checklists-idchecklist-checkitems) method.

[image: checkItems docs]